# Prepared Statement Batch update operation causes lock

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g db.
Using a prepared statement I am doing batch updates following is the code:

```
private void couponManualBatchBoxExecutePreparedStatement(List<Box> boxList, Long PartnerAccountId, Long cpnBatchId) throws Exception {

    String url = new COREResourceProperties().getValue("DATABASE_URL");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "ABC", "ABC");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); //keep auto commit false for better performance
    //query for inserting batch data
    String boxquery = "UPDATE PACKING_SERIAL SET CPNB_ID = ?, DLUO = ?, PACK_TYPE = 'B', CONTAINER_SERIAL = null WHERE SERIAL = ? AND PARTNER_ID = ?";
    String packquery = "UPDATE PACKING_SERIAL SET CPNB_ID = ?, DLUO = ?, PACK_TYPE = 'P', CONTAINER_SERIAL = ? WHERE SERIAL = ? AND PARTNER_ID = ?";

    PreparedStatement pBoxPackingSerialStatement = conn.prepareStatement(boxquery);
    PreparedStatement pPackPackingSerialStatement = conn.prepareStatement(packquery);

    List<String> boxSerialList = new ArrayList();
    int batchSize = 990;
    int recordSize = 1;

    for (Box box : boxList) {
        boxSerialList.add(box.getBoxSerial().toUpperCase());

        for (Pack pack : box.getPackList()) {
            if (batchSize >= recordSize) {
                Date CurrentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse((new Date()).toString());
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(CurrentTime);
                java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setLong(1, cpnBatchId);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setTimestamp(2, timestamp);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setString(3, box.getBoxSerial().toUpperCase());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setString(4, pack.getPackSerial());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setLong(5, PartnerAccountId);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.addBatch();
            } else {
                Date CurrentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse((new Date()).toString());
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(CurrentTime);
                java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setLong(1, cpnBatchId);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setTimestamp(2, timestamp);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setString(3, box.getBoxSerial().toUpperCase());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setString(4, pack.getPackSerial());
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.setLong(5, PartnerAccountId);
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.addBatch();
                pPackPackingSerialStatement.executeBatch();
                recordSize = 0;
            }

            recordSize++;
        }
    }

    for (String boxSerial : boxSerialList) {

        Date CurrentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse((new Date()).toString());
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(CurrentTime);
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
        pBoxPackingSerialStatement.setLong(1, cpnBatchId);
        pBoxPackingSerialStatement.setTimestamp(2, timestamp);
        pBoxPackingSerialStatement.setString(3, boxSerial);
        pBoxPackingSerialStatement.setLong(4, PartnerAccountId);
        pBoxPackingSerialStatement.addBatch();

    }


    pBoxPackingSerialStatement.executeBatch();
    pPackPackingSerialStatement.executeBatch();

    conn.commit();
    pBoxPackingSerialStatement.close();
    pPackPackingSerialStatement.close();
    conn.close();

}
```

This Code causes a lock in the database , the v$session event in oracle gives 'enq: TX - row lock contention'.
The program hangs on pBoxPackingSerialStatement.executeBatch();

Comment: any effort from end? Have you tried any thing?

Comment: No I did not try anything in the db. The code has to be avoid the lock.

Comment: Does the program hang always or only when the number of records to be updated crosses the batch size? My guess is that the locks are acquired because two updates are being fired on the same table at the same time. It doesn't seem to be related to the way java is executing queries. Another way to verify this would be to execute these queries on a sql developer.

Comment: It always hangs. The rows are unique in both the statement.

Comment: 1. Does it hang if you don't box packing prepared statement only?
2. Are the serial values unique ?

Comment: Yes, all the serial values are unique and its hangs,also, when  only boxstatement is executed and pack statement not executed.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that of Entity Manager it was some how locking the rows even though I did not use the table's entity bean for any query. 
The solution was to use JDBC's queries and prepared statement and not ORM.

Comment: here is a script to check the contention. This will show you also locked tables and blocking session https://www.crealoq.com/solved/Identify-Blocking-Session-Blocked-Session-Blocked-Statement-and-Locked-Objects-in-Oracle-DB